# How do we handle multiple setIntervals() in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express application which upon request to a route, calls a setInterval method. This method can lasts upto 20 mins as a whole and it has a job to take on random element from one array and append it to another.
Now the scenario is, if people make multiple requests to the route, multiple setIntervals will be spawned. Will the multiple setIntervals() be able to handle itself? As in, will there be a performance drop? Are multiple setIntervals() even possible to set? (it is not required to start all those instances of multiple intervals at the same time).

If there is a better way to handle such a task, what would it be?

Edit:
Added some code for better explanation.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var array2 = []
var job = () => { 
    const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    array2.append(randomElement);
    var index = array1.indexOf(randomElement);
    if (index > -1) {
    array1.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

var interval = 10;
var clear = false;

app.post("/test" ,(req ,res) => {
    //Can we have multiple setInterval() every time we request this route, without lack in performance?
    var loop = setInterval(() => {
        if (clear === true) {
            clearInterval(loop);
        } else {
            job();
        }
        });
    }, interval * 1000);
});

app.post("/clear" ,(req ,res) => {
    clear = true;
});
```

Comment: "_Will the multiple setIntervals() be able to handle itself?_" That depends on what you mean with handling. You can run multiple intervals, it doesn't affect to the performance more than running the same amount of code in some other way. Nested timeouts might work better (they won't cumulate), especially when the interval is short. If there's a better way is not known unless you show some code and introduce the exact intervals you're running. Though that question might be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ...

Comment: Hey Thank you for your reply. I have added some code that briefly explains what i want to do. I was thinking of dropping setInterval for some predefined Node framework like node-cron or agenda.js. Is it required in my case?

Comment: @eol  Thank you for replying, I changed the code a little bit. The use case is pretty simple. I have a mongo database holding arrays like array1 and array2 in the format `{ id: "someid" , array1: [1,2,3,4], array2: [] , clear: false}`. The `/test` actually has a request body which provides an id. The id  is then used to query the database and find the specific document. The document then fills in the value for array1 and array2 and can be used in the `job()` function. the job function updates the mongodb as well, so we are not storing anything on express(in memory).

Comment: @eol Consider each time the `/test` is called it is provided with a different id in the request parameter